# What do we mean by electromagnetic charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

What do you mean by charge? Why should a particle have a charge?

Comment: This is most likely a duplicate. Search around a bit before you ask? Also, being rude is not going to get  you very far here.

Comment: As a further note to the OP: *Had you bothered* to choose the most obvious title, i.e. "What is charge?", the *system itself* would have told you a question with that title already exists.

Comment: This isn't a bad question, I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: @LarryHarson: Look at how it looked before I edited, the downvotes are from then.